# Why the emphasis on Hebrew in Judaism?

Tags: hebrew, translation

Why does Judaism have such an emphasis on Hebrew phrases in their religion and seems reluctant to translate them to English or another language?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hebrew is the language of the Torah. The holy language. Translation inevitably creates a certain perspective on the text, as a Hebrew word can have multiple meanings or interpretations. A word for word translation would not make sense. The meaning often gets simplified, if not lost, in translation.

Answer (score 7):

Hebrew is called "leshon hakodesh" ("the holy language"). The Rambam ([Moreh Nevuchim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14118&st=&pgnum=486) 3:8) explains that the Hebrew language has no "bad words"; there are only euphemisms (to give one example, urine is called "the water of the legs"). Ramban ([Shemos 30:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14126&st=&pgnum=502)) writes that it is called holy because the Torah was written in that language, G-d is called by names in that language (vs. other languages — e.g. in English, "God" — in which the names don't have inherent holiness).

Answer (score -8):

for the same reason tha Muslims chose to pray in Arabic. And the same reason that the Roman Church has preserved the Latin Liturgy.

Comment: And what reason is that?

Comment: how do you know the reasons are the same?